# Reject promise, when don't know parent var

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, promise

I have this promise I simplified the code here but I can't get it to reject `promise0`. In example below, `renameProfile` first reads a file that holds all profile information, after reading it, it then tries to rename it which is done without promise. So in example `readFile` is success but rename file procedure fails. Yet it doesnt reject.

I am using Promise.jsm
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm

```
function doit() {
    var promise1 = renameProfile(1);
    promise1.then(
        function () {
            console.log('promise1 success');
        },
        function onReject(rsn) {
            console.log('promise1 failed rsn = ' + rsn);
        }
    );
    return promise1;
}

function renameProfile(readFileFirst) {
    if (readFileFirst == 1) {
        console.log('doing read file first');
        var promise2 = readFile();
        promise2.then(
            function () {
                console.log('promise2 success - read file success will now rename the profile');
                return renameProfile(0);
            },
            function (rsn) {
                console.log('promise2 failed - read file failed rsn = ' + rsn);
                return new Error('read file failed rsn = ' + rsn);
            }
        );
        return promise2;
    } else if (readFileFirst == 0) {
        //always reject promise
        console.log('doing renameProfile');
        return new Error('renameProfile failed');;
    }
}

function readFile() {
    let deferred = Promise.defer();
    deferred.resolve('successfully read file');
    return deferred.promise;
}

var promise0 = doit();
promise0.then(
    function () {
        console.log('promise0 success');
    },
    function (rsn) {
        console.log('promise0 failed rsn = ' + rsn);
    }
);
```

Comment: Promise is a specification... which library are you using? jQuery promises, or what?

Comment: Hey man I updated it to have this info. I am using firefox Promise.jsm, i also updated example so it works if u run it from scratchpad in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the point about actually (re-)throwing errors was already made... But that is not the only thing wrong here... `doIt()` will return the result `renameProfile(1)`, which is always `promise2 = readFile()` which is always successful.

What you meant to do would be to return not `promise2` but `promise2.then(...)`, which is another promise propagating the result or the `promise2` callback(s).

[`Promise.then()` returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise#then%28%29):

> A new promise that is initially pending, then assumes a state that
>   depends on the outcome of the invoked callback function:
>
> - If the callback returns a value that is not a promise, including undefined, the new promise is fulfilled with this fulfillment value,
>     even if the original promise was rejected.
> - If the callback throws an exception, the new promise is rejected with the exception as the rejection reason, even if the original
>     promise was fulfilled.
> - If the callback returns a promise, the new promise will eventually assume the same state as the returned promise.

So here is how I'd correct the code:

```
function doit() {
    var promise1 = renameProfile(1);
    promise1.then(
        function () {
            console.log('promise1 success');
        },
        function onReject(rsn) {
            console.log('promise1 failed rsn = ' + rsn);
        }
    );
    return promise1;
}

function renameProfile(readFileFirst) {
    if (readFileFirst == 1) {
        console.log('doing read file first');
        var promise2 = readFile();
        // !!! return the right thing.
        return promise2.then(
            function () {
                console.log('promise2 success - read file success will now rename the profile');
                return renameProfile(0);
            },
            function (rsn) {
                console.log('promise2 failed - read file failed rsn = ' + rsn);
                throw new Error('read file failed rsn = ' + rsn);
            }
        );
    } else if (readFileFirst == 0) {
        //always reject promise
        console.log('doing renameProfile');
        throw new Error('renameProfile failed');
    }
}

function readFile() {
    let deferred = Promise.defer();
    deferred.resolve('successfully read file');
    return deferred.promise;
}

var promise0 = doit();
promise0.then(
    function () {
        console.log('promise0 success');
    },
    function (rsn) {
        console.log('promise0 failed rsn = ' + rsn);
    }
);
```

(`promise1.then()` is just for logging and has no effect on the outcome).

Resulting in

```
"doing read file first" Scratchpad/1:16
"promise2 success - read file success will now rename the profile" Scratchpad/1:20
"doing renameProfile" Scratchpad/1:30
"promise1 failed rsn = Error: renameProfile failed" Scratchpad/1:8
"promise0 failed rsn = Error: renameProfile failed" Scratchpad/1:47
```

Comment: Quick question man, I think its true, I tested it, but just to verify, after a throw, it aborts the running right? So like `throw new Error('blah')` is the equivalent of putting `reuturn Promise.reject(new Error('blah'))`?

Answer (score 5):

Promises work just like synchronous code - you can throw errors at will.  In your case, you're *returning* an Error object, not throwing it.

```
throw new Error('renameProfile num == 2');
```

Should reject the promise and trigger your error handling.

Comment: thanks man ill test out throwing. i was returning new error, and it wasn't getting rejected. did you ever hear of returning errors as a way to reject a promise?

Comment: I updated example can you please take look, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: @SomeKittens Ux2666: You are absolutely right. After reading the document you posted it became clear that I didn't understand promises completely. Thank you for this hint.

Comment: I tried throwing instead of returning it didn't work :(

Comment: @Noitidart what do you mean "didn't work"?  The promise wasn't rejected?

Comment: No :( it still goes to success :(

Comment: @Noitidart remember, promises are __just like__ synchronous code. You're throwing an error, but then handling it with your onReject. This is akin to `try { throw new Error(); } catch(e){ console.log("promise1 failed..."); }` . Just like in synchronous code, if you want it to remain failed even after you handled the promise you _have_ to rethrow. Also watch out for the [Deferred Anti Patten](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help me out i think i might be getting an anti pattern or something Ill look into this. Thx all